# Trying to export queried data from access with a filter but when it opens in excel the data isn't filtered

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a large table in access and am using a query to bring in only certain fields I need. I'm then applying a filter to the queried data and trying to export the data into Excel. When the file opens in Excel it's only a portion of the data (since the table is so large) and the filter is no longer applied. Any advice?

The query is as follows (note the filter isn't in the SQL code I'm just using the drop down arrow in access):

```sql
SELECT [GSD Item Type Summary].[Prod Line], [GSD Item Type Summary].Year, [GSD Item Type Summary].[Prod Port], [GSD Item Type Summary].[Prod Type], [GSD Item Type Summary].[GBP Value]
FROM [GSD Item Type Summary];
```

Comment: Do you use for export to Excel the built-in Access functionality (the menu button) or you use code for it? We probably need to see the code to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'portion' - not all selected fields or not all records? Why export to Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter feature on an open Access table or via an Access datasheet form using one or more columns is simply a cosmetic GUI feature that only *hides* rows but does not remove records from data source. As MS Office [Apply a filter docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-a-filter-to-view-select-records-in-an-access-database-2a493ded-e544-4144-9103-b9b1d1865147) describes (emphasis added):

> Filtering is a useful way to see only the data that you want displayed
>   in Access databases. You can use filters to display specific records
>   in a form, report, query, or datasheet, or to print only certain
>   records from a report, table, or query. **By applying a filter, you are
>   able to limit the data in a view without altering the design of the
>   underlying object.**

Therefore, actually create an object to persist your filtering which you can do with an MS Access query object that actually applies your GUI filter(s) using a simple `WHERE` clause. Then open as any other table or via datasheet form and export this object to Excel.

**Single Filter**

```
SELECT g.[Prod Line], g.Year, g.[Prod Port], g.[Prod Type], g.[GBP Value]
FROM [GSD Item Type Summary] g;
WHERE g.[myTableColumn] = myFilterValue
```

**Multiple Filters**

```
SELECT g.[Prod Line], g.Year, g.[Prod Port], g.[Prod Type], g.[GBP Value]
FROM [GSD Item Type Summary] g;
WHERE g.[myTableColumn] = IN (myFilterValue1, myFilterValue2, myFilterValue3)
```

**Multiple Columns and Filters**

```
SELECT g.[Prod Line], g.Year, g.[Prod Port], g.[Prod Type], g.[GBP Value]
FROM [GSD Item Type Summary] g;
WHERE g.[myTableColumn1] = IN (myFilterValue1, myFilterValue2, myFilterValue3)
  AND g.[myTableColumn2] = IN (myFilterValue4, myFilterValue5, myFilterValue6)
  AND g.[myTableColumn3] = IN (myFilterValue7, myFilterValue8, myFilterValue9)
```